# Polymer load dynamic loaded pages

Tags: html, polymer

I am creating a web page that the content changes depending upon the logged in user.

The user content will change depending upon the info returned from user.pages info.

This is what im looking for basically

```
<user-signin></user-signin user="{{user}}">
<template repeat="{{page in user.pages}}">
<core-submenu id="{{page.name}}" label="{{page.name}}" hash="{{page.hash}}">
<template repeat="{{child in page.children}}">
    <core-item label="{{child.name}}" id="{{child.name}}" horizontal center layout hash="{{child.hash}}">
    </core-item>
</template>
</core-submenu>
</template>
```

**Pages**

```
<core-animated-pages fit id="pages" valueattr="hash" selected="{{$.main_menu.selected}}" transitions="slide-from-right">
        <section><help-desk/></section>
        <section><workers-page data="{{data}}"/></section>
        <section><log-page /></section>
        <template repeat="{{page in user.pages}}">
            <section hash="{{page.hash}}">
                <core-component-page sources='["{{page.content}}"]'></core-component-page>
            </section>
        </template>

</core-animated-pages>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you trying to do or what is the question?

Comment: Agreed. Please edit your question, so that we can best help you. BTW, Welcome to Stack Overflow!